# View every caught and handled exception from all threads

Tags: c#, visual-studio, multithreading, exception

How can I view all the caught and handled exceptions in C# application while debugging, so that I can view where all errors happened and how it was handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".  The debugger will now stop at any place an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Set the debugger to break on all exceptions.  By default, it won't break on handled first chance exceptions.

Comment: Chris can I make it show me a list without breaking on all exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

When using IntelliTrace, it lists all exceptions which was caught and handled without breaking on every exception thrown.